# How to assign recurring array elements as unique keys, and tally the corresponding integer values?

Tags: java, arrays, file, csv, hashmap

I've spent a while researching problems similar to mine, and am now stuck with my code. I have implemented a basic CSV file reader, but I'm stuck in processing the input

Current Result:

```
Source [medium = go bio , values = 5]
Source [medium = go bio , values = 5]
Source [medium = metal sink , values = 2]
Source [medium = go bio , values = 5]
Source [medium = metal sink , values = 3]
Done
```

But what I want is something like this.

Output:

```
[medium = go bio , values = 15]
[medium = metal sink , values = 5]
```

The contents of my text file.

```
go,bio,5
go,bio,5
metal,sink,2
go,bio,5
metal,sink,3
```

And this is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CVSReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CVSReader obj = new CVSReader();
        obj.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        String csvFile = "file2.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        String[] source;

        try {
            //HashMap here
            HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<String, Integer> hash2 = new HashMap<>();

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // comma separator here
                source = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                hash.put(source[0], source[0]);
                hash.put(source[1], source[1]);
                hash.put(source[2], source[2]);

                System.out.println("Source [medium = " + hash.get(source[0]) + " " +
                        hash.get(source[1]) + " , values = " + hash.get(source[2]) + "]");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a `Map<String, Integer>` to **add** your entries with the same key. Build the key, parse the value from your `line`, and if it's already in the `Map` add the current value to your parsed value. Then store the value back in the `Map`. I would also *prefer* a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Finally, iterate the `Map.entrySet()`. Something like,

```
String csvFile = "file2.txt";
String cvsSplitBy = "\\s*,\\s*"; // <-- adds support for white space(s)
                                 //     before or after the comma.
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
    Map<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] source = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        String medium = source[0] + " " + source[1]; // <-- the key
        int val = Integer.parseInt(source[2]);       // <-- the value
        if (hash.containsKey(medium)) { // <-- is the key in Map?
            val += hash.get(medium);    // <-- yes, add the value.
        }
        hash.put(medium, val); // <--  store the value back in the Map.
    }
    // Iterate the entry set, display the "medium" and value.
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("Source [medium = %s , values = %d]%n",
                entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
} catch (IOException e) { // <-- FileNotFoundException is a sub-class.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

Which I ran with your provided text file, and got (as requested)

> ```
> Source [medium = metal sink, values = 5]
> Source [medium = go bio, values = 15]
> Done
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, the comments they are very informative. I will read more about this, thanks again!